# Can you confirm my crontab line is right

Tags: cron

I want to set a cron job to run at 00h15 every Friday. Is this the correct way to do this:

```
15 0 * * 5
```

Comment: StackOverflow is specifically for *software development* questions. System configuration questions are out-of-scope (and even then, "please validate correctness of this code" would still be in violation of several rules, among them that we want questions to revolve around a specific, isolated bug or misbehavior; and also that questions should be useful to as many people as possible).

Answer (score 2):

Use this kind of website to validate your crons:
http://crontab.guru/#15_0_*_*_5